# El Capitan 10.11.3 Preview app missing move glove tool

Tags: preview

How can we get it back the Hand Tool (use to be a glove icon) for moving enlarged images in Preview (OS X El Capitan 10.11.3)?

This was most helpful tool Apple had for working with graphics!

Answer (score 1):

- Hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and you able to drag image.

  Or
- Draw small rectangular and drag it over image.